# Generate a drop-down list with dynamic range

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to create a drop-down list with a dynamic data range`worksheets(datasheet).range(cells(rng_rw_start,rng_cl_start),cells(rng_rw_end ,rng_cl_start )`. Both of its row and column are dynamic and generated by previous codes. Here's my codes:

```
 Dim datasheet as string
 Dim rng_rw_start as integer
 Dim rng_rw_end as integer
 Dim rng_cl_start as integer
 Dim rng_cl_end as integer
 set data_rng = worksheets(datasheet).range(cells(rng_rw_start,rng_cl_start),cells(rng_rw_end ,rng_cl_start ))
 set dropdown_cell = worksheets(datasheet).range("A5")
 With drop_down_cell.validation
           .Delete
           .Add Type:=xlValidateList, _
               Alertsytle:=xlvalidAlertstop, _
               Operator:=xlBetween, _
               Formula1:=data_rng
           .ErrorMessage = "Please select a wafer type from the list"
 End With
```

I think the problem is in "Formula1". I don't know how to refer to the dynamic data range. I have seen codes with dynamic rows like `Formula1:="='Sheet1'!$A$10:A" & LastRow`but not with columns and rows both dynamic.

An application-defined or object-defined error appears

Comment: try: `Formula1:= "=" & data_rng.Address(1,1,xlA1,1)`

Comment: @ScottCraner Tried and it is still showing " application-defined or object-defined error"...

Comment: ok try: `Formula1:= "='" & data_rng.Parent.Name & "'!" & data_rng.Address(1,1)`

Comment: One which line is it showing the error?

Comment: @ScottCraner the second is still showing error. The error is on the drop-down add line  -".Add Type:=xlValidateList, _
               Alertsytle:=xlvalidaalertstop, _
               Operator:=xlBetween, _
               Formula1:=data_rng"

Comment: remove the `Operator` line

Comment: @ScottCraner still doesn't work... same error message with the same line...

Comment: 1.  You have a typo in `xlvalidaalertstop` 2.  The validation list can only be one column.

Comment: @ScottCraner I corrected the typo and changed the validation source to one column but it still doesn't work... Thank you for your help

Comment: `.Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Formula1:="='" & data_rng.Parent.Name & "'!" & data_rng.Address(1, 1)` making sure `data_rng` is only one column.

Comment: @ScottCraner it works!! Thanks a lot!!